# Recursive Merge Sort Bug

Tags: c++, sorting, recursion, merge

I'm writing my own merge sort function for my own linked list class using C++. I have tested my Split_List and Merge functions and they work well. But I'm having trouble with the Merge_Sort recursive function: it can merge sort the left and right parts of the linked list but have error when finally merging the whole linked list.

output:

1st list:
[100]->[2]->[37]->[-10]->|||

sorted 1st list:
[37]->[100]->|||

node.h

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class node{
public:
    node(const T& data){item=data; link=NULL;}
    int item;
    node* link;
};

#endif // NODE_H
```

linked_list.h

```
#ifndef Linked_List_H
#define Linked_List_H
#include "node.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Linked_List{
public:
    Linked_List(){tail=head=NULL; count=0;}
    void Insert_Head(const T& item);
    void Append_Tail(const T& item);
    void Insertion_Sort();
    void Merge_Sort();
    void Print();
    int Size() {return count;}
private:
    node<T>* head;
    node<T>* tail;
    int count;
    void InsertHead(node<T>* &list_head, const T& item);
    void InsertBefore(node<T>* &list_head, node<T>* here, const T& item);
    void Append_Tail(node<T>* &list_head, node<T>* end);
    void Delete(node<T>* &list_head, node<T>* deleteHere);
    node<T>* DeleteHead(node<T>* &list_head);
    void Merge_Sort(node<T>* list_head, int size);
    node<T>* Merge(node<T>* left, node<T>* right);
    node<T>* Split_List(node<T>* list_head, int size);
    void Print(node<T>* list_head);
};

template<typename T>
void Linked_List<T>::Merge_Sort(){
    Merge_Sort(head, count);
}

template<typename T>
void Linked_List<T>::Merge_Sort(node<T>* list_head, int size){
    int n1;
    int n2;
    node<T>* right_head;

    if(size>1){
        right_head=Split_List(list_head, size);
        n1=size/2;
        n2=size-n1;
        Merge_Sort(list_head, n1);
        Merge_Sort(right_head, n2);
        head=Merge(list_head, right_head);
    }
}

template<typename T>
node<T>* Linked_List<T>::Split_List(node<T>* list_head, int size){
    if (size==0){
        return NULL;
    }else if (size==1){
        return list_head;
    }else{
        node<T>* iter=list_head;
        node<T>* right_head=NULL;
        int i=0;
        while (i<size/2-1){
            iter=iter->link;
            i++;
        }
        right_head=iter->link;
        iter->link=NULL;
        return right_head;
    }
}

template<typename T>
node<T>* Linked_List<T>::Merge(node<T>* left, node<T>* right){
    node<T>* newHead=NULL;
    while (left!=NULL && right!=NULL){
        if (left->item<=right->item){
            Append_Tail(newHead, DeleteHead(left));
        }else{
            Append_Tail(newHead, DeleteHead(right));
        }
    }
    if (left==NULL){
        while (right!=NULL){
            Append_Tail(newHead, DeleteHead(right));
        }
    }else{
        while (left!=NULL){
            Append_Tail(newHead, DeleteHead(left));
        }
    }
    return newHead;
}


template<typename T>
void Linked_List<T>::Insertion_Sort(){
    node<T>* end=head;
    while (end!=NULL){
        for (node<T>* iter=head; iter!=end; iter=iter->link){
            if (iter->item>=end->item){
                InsertBefore(head, iter, end->item);
                Delete(head, end);
                break;
            }
        }
        end=end->link;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void Linked_List<T>::Insert_Head(const T& item){
    InsertHead(head, item);
}

template<typename T>
void Linked_List<T>::InsertHead(node<T>* &list_head, const T& item){
    node<T>* tempPtr=new node<T> (item);     //create new node
    tempPtr->link=list_head;         //connect the new node to orignal 1st node
    list_head=tempPtr;               //make the head point to the new node as the new 1st node
    count++;
}

template <typename T>
void Linked_List<T>::InsertBefore(node<T>* &list_head, node<T>* here, const T& item){
    if (list_head==NULL || list_head==here)
    {
        InsertHead(head, item);      //add "head" node
        return;
    }else{
        node<T>* tempPtr=new node<T>(item);     //create new node

        node<T>* previous=head;
        while (previous->link!=here){
            previous=previous->link;        //if the previous node cannot be found, go to the link node
        }
        tempPtr->link=here;                 //if the previous node is found, connect the new node to "here" node
        previous->link=tempPtr;
        count++;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void Linked_List<T>::Append_Tail(const T& item){
    if (head==NULL)
    {
        InsertHead(head, item);      //add "head" node
        tail=head;
    }else{
        node<T>* tempPtr=new node<T>(item);     //create new node
        tail->link=tempPtr;
        tail=tail->link;
        count++;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void Linked_List<T>::Append_Tail(node<T>* &list_head, node<T>* end){
    if (list_head==NULL)
    {
        end->link=list_head;         //connect the new node to orignal 1st node
        list_head=end;               //make the head point to the new node as the new 1st node
        count++;
        tail=list_head;
    }else{
        tail->link=end;
        tail=tail->link;
        count++;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void Linked_List<T>::Delete(node<T>* &list_head, node<T>* deleteHere){
    node<T>* here=list_head;
    if (here==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Empty linked list!";             //empty linked list
        return;
    }
    else{
        node<T>* previous=list_head;
        if (deleteHere==list_head){
            list_head=deleteHere->link;              //if the deleted node is the 1st node, let the head point to the link node
            count--;
        }
        else{
            while (previous->link!=deleteHere){
                previous=previous->link;        //if the previous node cannot be found, go to the link node
            }
            previous->link=deleteHere->link;
            //if the previous node is found, connect the previous node to the node after the deleted node
            count--;
        }
    }
}

template<typename T>
node<T>* Linked_List<T>::DeleteHead(node<T>* &list_head){
    node<T>* deleted=list_head;
    list_head=list_head->link;              //if the deleted node is the 1st node, let the head point to the link node
    count--;
    deleted->link=NULL;
    return deleted;
}


template<typename T>
void Linked_List<T>::Print(){
    Print(head);
}

template<typename T>
void Linked_List<T>::Print(node<T>* list_head){
    node<T>* iter;
    for (iter=list_head; iter!=NULL; iter=iter->link){
        cout<<"["<<(iter->item)<<"]->";
    }
    cout<<"|||"<<endl<<endl;
}

#endif // Linked_List_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "linked_list.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Linked_List<int> list1;
    list1.Insert_Head(-10);
    list1.Insert_Head(37);
    list1.Insert_Head(2);
    list1.Insert_Head(100);
    cout<<"1st list: "<<endl;
    list1.Print();

    cout<<"sorted 1st list: "<<endl;
    list1.Merge_Sort();
    list1.Print();
}
```

Comment: Did you use the debugger to debug your code? Did you write out your plan on paper first before writing the code? If so, and when you debug, where in the logic does it go against your plan? You should know at a much lower level than "it doesn't work on merging the last two items". What variable(s) are not correct? What function is or is not being called? Etc.. Etc..

Comment: After you get this working, you might want to consider a bottom up type merge sort that uses an array of pointers to nodes, where array[i] points to a list of size 2^i (with array[n-1] unlimited in size). 26 to 32 pointers in the array would be fine. It's a much faster algorithm. If interested, I can post example code later as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add some excessive `Print` calls in your code, you'll see your problem. You sort the size-2 lists correctly, but in the top-level one, after:

```
Merge_Sort(list_head, n1);
Merge_Sort(right_head, n2);
```

`list_head` will be the list `[100]->|||` and `right_head` will be the list `[37]->|||`. You're actually merging and sorting correctly, it's just that those pointers don't change, so you start with:

```
[100] -> [2] -> Nil
  ^
  list_head
```

And end up with:

```
[2] -> [100] -> Nil
         ^
         list_head
```

And similarly for the other list. So as far as you're concerned at that point, you're just merging two lists of size one, which you do correctly - that's how you end up with just `37` and `100`.

That should point you in the right direction.